# What IP addresses should I have listed to access my google cloud SQL instance?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, gcloud

So Im following the [google ruby guide](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/getting-started/using-cloud-sql) to create and setup a cloud sql instance. Under 'Create and configure a Cloud SQL instance' step 4 it tells you to allow all network fields so the instance is open to all traffic, then underneath that it gives the warning:

`This configuration leaves your Cloud SQL instance open to traffic from everyone, everywhere. It is used only for demonstration purposes. In production environments, restrict access to only those IP addresses that need access.`

I haven't setup VM servers on a cloud environment before so I have no idea on what IP addresses I should be giving access to the SQL instance or what ones 'need access' do I just change it to the IP of my VMs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of the guide that you linked, the IP whitelist is necessary so you can access your Cloud SQL instance from your development server on your local computer. For that specific purpuse, you can just whitelist your computer's IP (see http://www.whatsmyip.org) instead off all the world.

When your application is going to be running on App Engine, you don't need to whitelist the IP. There is a separate access control list for that in the Cloud Console where you can list the App Engine applications authorized to connect.

Comment: I marked this as correct but I'm finding that if I remove the ip 0.0.0.0/0 (allowing all networks) then the deploy doesn't work and I get sql connection issues.

Comment: Connection issues from where?

Comment: The site goes down with an error of 'We're sorry, but something went wrong.' unless I have that network saved. and I cant deploy unless I have that network saved

Comment: Where is your site running? You need to find the IP address of the server running the site - that is the IP address you should whitelist on your instance. Leaving 0.0.0.0/0 as your authorized network is unsafe and should be avoided if possible.